# Why cannot I create a dynamic delegate which has more than one argument using .NET EMIT

Tags: c#, .net, reflection.emit

There are some definations:

```cs
public class Message
{
    public SayType Say(string name)
    {
        Console.Write("Hello," + name );
        return SayType.Name;
    }
    
    public SayType Say(string name,string haha)
    {
        Console.Write("Hello," + name );
        return SayType.Name;
    }
}

public enum SayType
{
    Name
}
```

SayDelegate:

```cs
public delegate SayType SayDelegate(object message,params object[] o);
```

And I want to create two dynamic of the two function in class Message.
The first:

```cs
DynamicMethod dynamicMethod = 
             new DynamicMethod("Say",typeof(SayType),new Type[]{typeof(object),typeof(object[])});
        var il = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg,0); 
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg,1); 
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4,0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelem_Ref);  
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,typeof(Message).GetMethods()[0]);
        //[0] refers to the first method 
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret); 
        System.Delegate delegates = dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(SayDelegate));
        delegates.DynamicInvoke(new Message(), new object[]{"123123"});
```

It can work normally.

However, if I create the second delegate like this:

```cs
DynamicMethod dynamicMethod = 
             new DynamicMethod("Say",typeof(SayType),new Type[]{typeof(object),typeof(object[])});
        var il = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg,0); 
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg,1); 
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4,0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelem_Ref); 
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4,1); 
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelem_Ref); 
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,typeof(Message).GetMethods()[1]);
        //[1] refers to the second method 
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret); 
        System.Delegate delegates = dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(SayDelegate));
        delegates.DynamicInvoke(new Message(), new object[]{"123123","123123"});
```

It will have some complains:

```
 ---> System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
   at Say(Object , Object[] )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: Please show us the signature for `SayDelegate` - ideally reframing the whole thing as a [mcve] that we can copy/paste/compile/run.

Comment: Arg0 is typed as object, you never cast it - related? However, I always advise: write what you want to do in C# and decompile it, compare the difference; sharlpab.io is great for that

Comment: @JonSkeet `SayDelegate` is as the same as the `Say` method in class Message. The two delegates refer to two methods in Class Message

Comment: @DamXosp4j there are two `Say` methods. Do you mean the first one? why not just show the delegate declaration so we don't need to guess?

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, but it is strange that I do not need to cast them if they are referrence types which are used as object type (except for value type which need cast.).

Comment: you should still emit a castclass - failing to do so is ... well, at best "unverifiable", but honestly: still should be done

Comment: @MarcGravell. Sorry, but in the question I use the two methods both. The first dynamic delegate is as the same as the first method which has one argument. It can be created normally. However, the second dynamic delegate is as the same as the second method which has two arguments but cannot work normally. I mentioned the difference of two dynamic delegate in the code annotation.

Comment: See the IL for what you seem to want here? https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwAEAmARgFgAoQgBgAJDSA6AJRgDNcYwNsIA7JgFEAttgwBuKlQAmMLgHMAhhhh0AykoCeAFS0AHNZq0AReTGWqAFBGAArbhjoI0dWw54BtALp0tASilqAGYGYjoAWRgAZ2ilBRgqAG8qOjSGUOM9Qw1tK0Z6fiURGH9U9JTKdOq6AGEBaIguJgB1KHEYKwAiAAl5XAg0LroAajoiksDymoYAdlzdAxgmADlimCDqgF9pKvTCTO1sozyC8fXXM4ALJRuyvbTKmbT6/kbmto7uvtwBodHzpNNs9CPMsktVutgWkdpRYVQDnQYPwAK4iBbHZLTOhrEpUeHUUhIMJ0AAKWIeDCJGKWdBaNwwAE0ICiWkp+BgbPZHM5XO5HD4/Pdqk8QfMrFYorF4qUEP4mMYJQV/FpPDRvK58qQaCrPKRvFNKbCtkA===

Comment: And from that, it took about 10 seconds to find the missing ldarg.1 - although I still **highly** recommend adding the missing casts

Comment: @MarcGravell. It is amazing... I have tried to find the error using dotPeek, however I cannot find the bug. (Maybe I am not using the function which is mostly simliar to the delegate....)Thank you very much!!! And I am trying to add the cast just as what you said.

Comment: another trick is to use comments to track what is on the stack at every point - but that also assumes you update the comments accurately; a *3rd* option is to use `Sigil`, a nuget package for IL manipulation that makes errors very very clear

Comment: @MarcGravell. Thank you very much and I am trying to learn about what you said !

Comment: *Please* also take from this that it's useful to provide a *complete* example. Why make us ask questions and then just *describe* the delegate, when it would be trivial to make this a compilable example that we could just run? Even though it's now been answered, I strongly encourage you to edit the question to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: @JonSkeet . Sorry , and I add `SayDelegate`. Now it can run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a `ldarg.1`:

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, 0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, 1);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelem_Ref);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, 1); // <<== this one
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 1);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelem_Ref);
```

The trick is to [compile and decompile what you want](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwAEAmARgFgAoQgBgAJDSA6AJRgDNcYwNsIA7JgFEAttgwBuKlQAmMLgHMAhhhh0AykoCeAFS0AHNZq0AReTGWqAFBGAArbhjoI0dWw54BtALp0tASilqAGYGYjoAWRgAZ2ilBRgqAG8qOjSGUOM9Qw1tK0Z6fiURGH9U9JTKdOq6AGEBaIguJgB1KHEYKwAiAAl5XAg0LroAajoiksDymoYAdlzdAxgmADlimCDqgF9pKvTCTO1sozyC8fXXM4ALJRuyvbTKmbT6/kbmto7uvtwBodHzpNNs9CPMsktVutgWkdpRYVQDnQYPwAK4iBbHZLTOhrEpUeHUUhIMJ0AAKWIeDCJGKWdBaNwwAE0ICiWkp+BgbPZHM5XO5HD4/Pdqk8QfMrFYorF4qUEP4mMYJQV/FpPDRvK58qQaCrPKRvFNKbCtkA===), and look at the IL; in this case we see:

```
IL_0000: ldarg.0
IL_0001: castclass Message
IL_0006: ldarg.1
IL_0007: ldc.i4.0
IL_0008: ldelem.ref
IL_0009: castclass [System.Runtime]System.String
IL_000e: ldarg.1
IL_000f: ldc.i4.1
IL_0010: ldelem.ref
IL_0011: castclass [System.Runtime]System.String
IL_0016: callvirt instance valuetype SayType Message::Say(string, string)
IL_001b: ret
```

and compare that to your opcodes (noting that you're using unsafe coerce, which ... I'm not going to advocate for, but I also can't stop you from doing)